# CakePHP Radio Buttons

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, radio-button

I am using CakePHP to create a simple blog for myself.  I want to have a rating system attached to each post.

I have loaded the ratings which look like this:

**Controller**

```
$this->set('ratings', $this->Ratings->find('all'));
```

I want to generate radio buttons on the view with the ratings.  The ratings have the fields `value` and `label`.  I could use a `foreach` and loop around the ratings but I am wondering if the radio button helper in the form class can take a model object and generate the radio buttons?

I hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass an options attribute to the form helper.

```
<?=$this->Form->input('rating', array('type' => 'radio', 'options' => range(1, 10)))?>
```

Comment: Gotcha cheers. Was passing the options and html attributes in the wrong order.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$options = array(
    '0' => 'Male',
    '1' => 'FeMale'
);

$attributes = array(
    'legend' => false,
    'value' => 0
);

echo $this->Form->radio('type', $options, $attributes);
```